# Javascript uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying get and set image src using javascript and i keep getting this error:

> uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null.

I have search Stackoverflow and could not find a solution. Here is my code

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
       <img src="" id="modalImg">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <script>
    function viewProduct(product_id){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/view_product_details/?product_id=' + product_id, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4){
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('exampleModalLongTitle').innerHTML = data.name
            document.getElementById('modalBody').innerHTML = data.description
            document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src', data.image_url)
            document.getElementById('img').src = data.image_url}}
    request.send();}
    </script>
```

Comment: The only image in the source has the id `modalImg`, not `img`

Comment: there is no element with the id="img"

Comment: The error means that somewhere in your code is `whatever.src` and `whatever` is undefined.

Comment: I still get the same error with this code document.getElementById('modalImg').setAttribute('src', data.image_url)
document.getElementById('modalImg').src = data.image_url

Comment: Is it possible that the script is executed before the page is fully loaded? Make sure that request.send(); is only executed from document.onLoad event.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any element with the id `img`. The only image object has the ID `modalImg` then your getElementById should be this:

```
document.getElementById('modalImg').setAttribute('src', data.image_url)
document.getElementById('modalImg').src = data.image_url
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry @Quentin I'll take consider of your advices for next answers.

Comment: Sorry i posted a wrong code document.getElementById('img').src = data.image_url instead of document.getElementById('modalImg').setAttribute('src', data.image_url)

Comment: Its still shows the same error with this code document.getElementById('modalImg').setAttribute('src', data.image_url)